# subset a vector of column names by a particular sample prefix

Tags: r

Lets say I have a data frame that looks like this

```
ca01<- c(1:10)
ca02<- c(2:11)
ca03<- c(3:12)
stuff.1<- rep('test',10)
other<- rep(9,10)

data<- data.frame(ca01,ca02,ca03,stuff.1,other)
```

I then create a vector that contains the column names

```
samps<- colnames(data)
```

I then want to filter this vector to only contain items that begin with the prefix "ca". I do not want to exclude stuff.1 and other by writing individual lines of code that remove these specifically, so something like

```
samps<-samps[samps!='stuff.1']
samps<-samps[samps!='other']
```

would not be suitable.

Comment: `data[!grepl("^ca", samps)]`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try using `grepl`

```
> Names <- colnames(data)
> Names[grepl("^ca", Names)]
[1] "ca01" "ca02" "ca03"
```

Answer (score 4):

Just in case you want to use that vector to subset the data later on, here's how you could do such thing using the package dplyr. It has a function `select` to select/unselect columns of a data.frame and within that function you can use a variety of special selection functions. In this case because you want to select those columns with a prefix you can use the special function called `starts_with()`. Here's how it would look like:

```
library(dplyr)

data %>% 
  select(starts_with("ca"))
#   ca01 ca02 ca03
#1     1    2    3
#2     2    3    4
#3     3    4    5
#4     4    5    6
#5     5    6    7
#6     6    7    8
#7     7    8    9
#8     8    9   10
#9     9   10   11
#10   10   11   12
```

There are other selection functions you could use in other cases, for example `ends_with`, `contains`, `one_of` etc. You can read about it by typing `?select` after loading the package.

The `%>%` is a forward pipe operator which you can use to create a pipe or chain of several commands and forward the data from one function to the next.