# Select multiple columns by name in R

Tags: r

I'm relatively new to R, so maybe this is really basic. But I need to select multiple columns from a data frame by name in R. I know the columns I want are all adjacent. I know the name of the first column and the last column. And in my case in particular all columns have names of the form XYYYY where 'X' is the letter X and the 'Y's are numbers representing years, but some years may be omitted (I don't know whether or not any of the years in my range are omitted just that the data set is missing some years.) Is there a way to do this that doesn't involve looping an selecting each column individually until I get to the last one?

Comment: Welcome to SO. This is a very basic R question and SO is not really the place for "learning R from scratch". The core use of SO is to post data and code and then indicating the components you tried and did not work. This falls out of scope of that unless you can review the guidance here — https://stackoverflow.com/tags/r/info — and post a reproducible example (data + code) of something you tried.

Comment: Look into dplyr's select function. It can be combined with the starts_with function to select all columns that start with X, for example.

Comment: This is a dup of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24250878/selecting-multiple-columns-in-data-frame-using-partial-column-name (someone who can still vote to close it should do that as a dup)

Comment: This might fall out of the scope of what is appropriate for SO, but it is most certainly not a dupe of the question hrbrmstr posted.

Comment: @JackSurine - maybe something like - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29219939/subset-a-vector-of-column-names-by-a-particular-sample-prefix ?

Answer (score -4):

Use select function, you can either use indices or column names for selection
for example,

1. for selecting 1 and 2 columns use: select(1:3)
2. for selecting columns by names: select(a,b) [ Note: a, b are column names]

Comment: You've just told someone very new to R to use a function — `select()` — that's not in base R and have not provided which package they should try to use to get that into their namespace. Furthermore, you did not answer their core question which is how to select columns with similar naming-structure without hand-specifying all of them. This is confusing and unhelpful for the OP.

Comment: Sorry that I forgot that you are using the baseR, you can use subset functionality. please refer to https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/base/versions/3.5.1/topics/subset

Comment: How is `subset()` going to help with multiple column selection by partial name matching?